# Text imported into SQL Server using ogr2ogr had extra characters at the beginning

Tags: sql-server, mapinfo, ogr2ogr, sql-server-spatial

I've managed to import some MapInfo data sets into SQL Server using ogr2ogr

But when I run a query in SQL Management Studio (SSMS), the various text fields look to be "blank"

However if I use the SUBSTRING function to trim off the first couple of characters, e.g. `SUBSTRING(NAME, 3, 20)`, the text is displayed when I run the SQL query